# How to refresh OpenFileDialog .txt file in Label (VB)?

Tags: vb.net, timer, updates, streamreader

My VB application should read text using a StreamReader and show the .txt file contents in a label:

```
Private Sub FileLocationButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FileLocationButton.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    If OpenFileDialog1.FileName <> "" Then
        Dim SR As New StreamReader(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)

        Do Until SR.EndOfStream
            Label6.Text = Label6.Text & SR.ReadLine & vbCrLf
        Loop
        SR.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

I am writing and saving the text file in MS Word etc. and would like to view the updated version of the file (the text) in the vb app.
Therefore:
I have added a timer and would like to know what code would allow the application to refresh the label with it's new text (from the .txt file) every 3 seconds so that the new content I just typed in MS Word/Notepad etc. will show?

Comment: Don't use a Timer when it can tell you when the file changed.  Use FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: I am very new to VB and would appreciate it if you could give me the corresponding code using the FileSystemWatcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a timer to refresh the text in the label. In the form designer, drag a Timer from the toolbox onto your main form (Form1). Add a FilePath property to your preferences form (Preferences1) and use it to store the path selected in the OpenFileDialog. When you show the preferences form, save its path in a class level variable in the main form and start the timer with an interval of 3000 (this is milliseconds, so 3000 is 3 seconds). In the timer Tick event, read the file again and replace the text in the label. Note that the following code uses File.ReadAllText to read the file (and close it) in one statement.

In the main form (Form1) you have this code

```
Private textFile As String

Sub PrefButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PrefButton.Click
    Using pref As New Preferences1 
        pref.ShowDialog
        textFile = pref.FilePath 
    End Using
    If textFile <> "" Then Label6.Text = File.ReadAllText(textFile)
    Timer1.Interval = 3000
    Timer1.Start 
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
  Handles Timer1.Tick
    If textFile <> "" Then Label6.Text = File.ReadAllText(textFile)
End Sub
```

In the preferences form (Preferences1) you have this code

```
Private myPath As String
Public ReadOnly Property FilePath As String
    Get
        Return myPath
    End Get
End Property 

Private Sub FileLocationButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
  Handles FileLocationButton.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then 
        myPath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code Blackwood, however one thing I forgot to mention is that I now have two forms, the main form (Form1) and the Preferences form (Preferences1).     I am getting an error (yellow highlighting) over the 'Label6.Text = File.ReadAllText(textFile)' saying    "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: path"    ArgumatNullException was unhandled.     Do I put the timer on Form1 or Preferences1?    Will it update when preferences is closed?

Comment: Do you mean that the file is selected in the preferences form, but the label is in the main form (Form1)? If so, which form is the startup form (the one that loads when your application starts) and how does it show the other form. You should probably make the filepath a public property of your main form; how you update that from the preferences form depends on how they are each being shown.

Comment: Correct, the startup form is form 1 and the preferences 1 menu is accessed via context menu strip. When the txt file is chosen in the preferences. Then then is should display and refresh the file contents in Label6 on the startup form (main form/form1). I need the code that updates the label with the new text every 3 secs and without crashing due to what I wrote in my previous comment. My whole application depends on this last part.

Comment: OK. I have updated my answer to split the code between a preferences form where the user select the text file and a main form where the label is. Note that I assumed you are calling the preferences as a Dialog (with ShowDialog), but the same approach should work if your call it as a regular form (with Show).

Comment: I am getting 2 errors in the last code (preferences):    Error 1 Property without a 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifier must provide both a 'Get' and a 'Set'.    Error 2 Statement cannot appear within a property body. End of property assumed.

Comment: It sounds like you using a very old version of Visual Studio (2008 or earlier) that doesn't support Auto-Implemented Properties. In that case, you will need a few additional line of code. I'll update my answer to do that.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, yes my version is '08, but I am about to download the latest one (and use your previous code). This answer helped me out majorly. Thank You @Blackwood.